# Leave System Balance on a HR application Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'll just head on to the question directly, I'm currently trying to build an HR(Human Resources) Application on Laravel and at the Leave System where a user can take a specific type of Leave(Vacation and such), I would like to create a Balance system where the user selects a date from and date to and that number in between them gets deducted from the main balance that a user has and that would be the number 20 which I added to my user table on a field called leave_balance(the number is set by default as 20 when a user is created).

Now except deducting the number I would also like to add a function somehow that adds a specific number to the leave_balance every day ex 0.05 I am suspecting I can do this with carbon but I have not the slightest idea how since im relatively new to Laravel

So this is the Leave Table(it is not connected by a foreign key with the user's table):

1. id
2. user_id
3. from
4. to
5. type
6. description
7. status
8. message

The user_id is only there to store the id of the authenticated user who creates a leave it is not related by a foreign key

This is what I was thinking of adding in the LeaveController:

```
// checks for table if employee leave is at 0
$employee = DB::table('leaves')->where('id', $id)->where('leave', 0)->get()->all();
$employeeObj = DB::table('leaves')->where('id', $id)->get()->all();

// init for needed condition
$leaveBool = false;
if(sizeof($employee) < 1) {
  $leaveBool = true;
}

// leave is not at 0
if(!$leaveBool) {
  DB::table('leaves')->update([
    'id' => $id,
    'leave'       => $employeeObj['leaves'] - 1,
  ]);
}
```

I would like to fix this code so that I can add this in the Leave Controller(also if it's possible to explain to me where exactly I should put such a code in the controller) by fix I mean to not just removed -1 but the number between "from" and "to"

I'm not sure if these are helpful but I will post them too just to make it easier to see,

This is the Leave Model:

```
class Leave extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded=[];
    
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');   
     }
}
```

This is the view of the Leave

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('leaves.store')}}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>From Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control @error('from') is-invalid @enderror" name="from" required="">

                                @error('from')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>To Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="datepicker1" type="text" class="form-control @error('to') is-invalid @enderror" name="to" required="">
```

I used datepicker for the date, this would be a visualization of what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Also by any means, if you have a better code or idea on how I can do this do share it your way it may probably be heaps better

Comment: apart from the coding, are you aware of how the laws about leave are. Per example in my country, if there is a general holiday, it won't count as a leave day. just to keep in mind

Comment: Yeah I understand that but since its only, a simple leave application it's not taking the general holidays or Saturday/Sunday into consideration for now

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Are you struggling to calculate the number of days between the two input dates (from and to)?

Comment: Im asking on how to create a logic that adds a specific number every day on a table and also if the code that I want to use on the controller needs editing based on the new logic

Comment: What's your exact question on this topic? Where to put the code? That's pretty opion based, but it should not be put in a controller, as this makes testing and refactoring pretty hard

Comment: I see but if not the controller where else is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you make a method `leaveBalance()` on the `User`. Since it somewhat of a computed property this might make it easier than keeping the numbers right when creating/deleting/updating `Leave` objects. To do that add a property `leave_days_granted` on the `User` (defaults to 20). Remove `leave_balance`.

Then you could do something like:

```
class User
{
    public function leaveBalance()
    {
        $daysUsed = $this->leaves->map->numberOfDays()->sum();
        return $this->leave_days_granted - $daysUsed;
    }

    // You can also add a helper to make your controller more readable.
    public function hasAvailableLeave()
    {
        return $this->leaveBalance() > 0;
    }

    public function leaves()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Leave::class);
    }

}
```

Leave model:

```
class Leave
{
    protected $dates = ['from', 'to'];

    public function numberOfDays()
    {
        return $this->from->diffInDays($to);
    }
}
```

---

#### Comment on leaveBalance method:

- `$this->leaves` references the relationship method `leaves()`. Using it without `()` will automatically retrieve the related items.
- `->map->numberOfDays()` is shorthand for

  ```
    ->map(function($leave) {
        return $leave->numberOfDays();
    })
  ```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the numberOfDays() helper I'm relatively new to laravel so I don't quite understand what I should do at that part

Comment: Added Leave class example

Comment: Hi im sorry for replying late im just using this again and I wanted to be sure about something at the part about the helper to make the controller more readable how does that part work? I didn't get to use that before but I want to include it too(sorry for the weird question im new to laravel so im still learning these thank you)

Comment: Also how to save the sum that returns on the database? It still shows number 20 even after creating

Comment: I added the exact code you suggested on the user and leave model and created the field leave_days_granted but when I still create a leave the default 20from that field still isn't changing maybe it has something to do that there are no relations in the database with the 2 tables? Maybe I should do a type of foreign key relationship or such? Currently, it only saves the id of the user that requests a leave on the user_id and then it only shows that users leaves I will include these pictures of the database and form maybe im doing something wrong?

Comment: This is the form [link](https://imgur.com/vG2DvS6)
This is the users table [link](https://imgur.com/xN19QfC)
This is the leaves table [link](https://imgur.com/54t2MIx)